# How can I make a dummy shell take no arguments in C?

Tags: c, shell, parameters, arguments

I have a dummy shell program that takes arguments.  However, I want it to take no arguments and instead provide a prompt to let the user input the name of executable program and parameters.

For example:

```
$dummyshell
>(executable program and parameters go here)
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
  char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
  char **temp;
  char *buf;
  size_t n, p;

  cmdArgs[0], buf, bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

  for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
    if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
      break;
  }

  for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
    if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
      cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
  }

  *nargs=p;
  cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
  char hflag = 'N';
  int *retStatus;
  size_t nargs;
  pid_t pid;

  while(1){

    printf("$dummyshell ");
    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


    if (nargs==0)
      continue;

    if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
      {
    printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
        printf("exit\n");
        printf("help                   history\n");
        printf("jobs                   kill\n");
        printf("ls                     more\n");
        printf("ps                     pwd\n");
    continue;
      }

    if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
      exit(0);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid){      
      pid = wait(retStatus);
    }

    else {
      if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
    puts(strerror(errno));
    exit(127);
      }
    }

  }    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the line `cmdArgs[0], buf, bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;` does? It actually evaluates the uninitialized `cmdArgs[0]` and throws it away; then the uninitialized `buf` and throws that away, and finally assigns to `bufCmdArgs[0]`.  If you want to assign to all three variables, use assignment operators in place of the comma operator: `cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;`. Since you don't seem to use `buf`, you may as well leave that out (definition and initialization).

Comment: I see I misspoke about `buf`; it is used. Sorry. That's the trouble with eyeballing code. Separately, you'll also eventually realize that both the commands `cd` and `exit` (and probably `history` too) require special attention; they are shell built-ins for a good reason.  That, however, comes later.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know of a way to modify my program so that if the user types a '&' symbol at the end of the program and its parameters, the dummy shell will run the program in the background rather than the foreground?

Comment: Neither `hflag` nor the arguments to `main()` are used; get rid of them (`int main(void)`).  You should include `<sys/wait.h>`; you should change `retStatus` to a simple `int` and then pass `&retStatus` to `wait()`. Failing that, you need to initialize `retStatus` so it points to an `int` that can be assigned to.  With those changes, the code runs OK – sort of.  It executed `ls -l` correctly.  However, control-D (EOF) to exit failed horribly.

Comment: Is this in response to my above comment?  I did what you said.  However, I think you're thinking of control-C?

Comment: On my machine, it is control-D to indicate EOF at the terminal. Typing control-C generates an interrupt.  I typed control-D first; your code didn't test the return value from `fgets()` properly, so it didn't notice that it was getting the 'same command' over and over because the `fgets()` call was failing and not modifying the string.  The interrupt stopped the shell; fortunately, you've not added interrupt handling yet.

Comment: "cd" is not a program you can (meaningfully) exec(). It sounds like your dummyshell is better written as a shell function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think this line does?

```
cmdArgs[0], buf, bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;
```

It actually evaluates the uninitialized `cmdArgs[0]` and throws it away; then it evaluates the uninitialized `buf` and throws that away, and finally assigns to `bufCmdArgs[0]`. If you want to assign to all three variables, use assignment operators in place of the comma operator:

```
cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;
```

Neither `hflag` nor the arguments to `main()` are used; get rid of them (`int main(void)`). You should `#include <sys/wait.h>`; you should change `retStatus` to a simple `int` and then pass `&retStatus` to `wait()`. Failing that, you need to initialize `retStatus` so it points to an `int` that can be assigned to.

With those changes, the code runs OK – sort of. It executed `ls -l` correctly. However, <kbd>control-D</kbd> (EOF) to exit failed horribly (I got to see the plain `ls` listing of my directory quite a lot before I was able to interrupt it.

Separately, you'll also eventually realize that both the commands cd and exit (and probably history too) require special attention; they are shell built-ins for a good reason. That, however, comes later.

> Do you know of a way to modify my program so that if the user types a '&' symbol at the end of the program and its parameters, the dummy shell will run the program in the background rather than the foreground?

Yes, I do know of ways to do that.  Basically, you don't do the `wait()` (and when you do `wait()`, you check whether the dead process you collect information on is the one you expected, or whether it is one of your shell's background processes.

---

#### Semi-working code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  //int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    while(1){

        printf("$dummyshell ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid){      
            pid = wait(&retStatus);
        }

        else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
                puts(strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

You might note that error messages should be reported on standard error, not standard output (so `puts(strerror(errno))` should be `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));` because `fputs()` doesn't add a newline but `puts()` does).

Comment: Thank you so much, I've updated the parts that I understood.  My program is supposed to generate a new prompt line when control-C is typed instead of terminating the program.  How would I go about doing that?  Also, I have no idea how to use wait() while differentiating between background and foreground processes.

Comment: The control-C handling is also 'signal handling'; look up [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)
 and its relatives. You will need to keep a track of the PID of which child process you are waiting for (for synchronous commands, without an `&` at the end), and ignore, or report on, the other processes that `wait()` returns.  Time to go hit the manuals again.  You were pretty close with your original code.  I've critiqued many far worse programs.  Also look on SO for other DIY shell questions; there are many of them.