# How can I make my dummy shell run a program in the background?

Tags: c, shell, background, fork, wait

I want the user to be able to type and input a program and its parameters but if the user types a "&" at the end, the dummyshell should run the program in the background.  In this case, the dummyshell will return immediately a prompt to users (for further command inputs).  I know I have to use wait() but I'm not sure how to use it in order to run a program in the background.

For example when program runs in foreground:

```
$ dummyshell
> HelloWorld
...
>
```

For example when program runs in background:

```
$ dummyshell
> HelloWorld &
>
```

This is the code I'm working with so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  //int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    while(1){

        printf("$dummyshell ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid){      
            pid = wait(&retStatus);
        }

        else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just skip the `wait`/`waitpid` call, and handle the [`SIGCHLD`](http://www.google.com/search?q=sigchld) signal asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah but how do I detect if the user has inputted an '&' at the end?

Comment: You should use: `if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0) break;` to handle EOF from the terminal cleanly.  I mentioned that in my answer to your previous (related, but not duplicate) question.

Comment: To detect the `&`, you look for it. In standard shells, both `sleep 3&` and `sleep 3 &` work the same, but they are both different from `sleep 3>&1` and `sleep 3 && echo Hi`.

Comment: @user2264035 Now that's an entirely different question! "How to I detect an & at the end of a string". Just work out the parsing details, it's been done a million times before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think you mentioned that in my previous question.  So is that if statement to check if the EOF is reached?

Comment: Yes, I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061913/how-can-i-make-a-dummy-shell-take-no-arguments-in-c) that your code did not handle EOF well; and yes, that `if` is to handle the case where `fgets()` detects EOF.  I said: _However, control-D (EOF) to exit failed horribly (I got to see the plain `ls` listing of my directory quite a lot before I was able to interrupt it)._